Airpods pro 2 jittering sound
I have an Apple Airpods Pro, every once in a while sound starts to jitter (silence then sound repeatedly). I'm using it on a Dell laptop and Huawei Y6S Phone. Searching around the following has been suggested and done by me with no success:

Some pages suggested that there is too much radio interference, I tried to sit in an isolated zone, no luck.
Other pages that Bluetooth driver on my Dell laptop is outdated, I updated it.
Also some have suggested that maybe it's a YouTube issue or music app issue, I have changed both, nothing seems to be working.

I would appreciate some help, thanks
